# How do I release a wear compatible app along with my app?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an android app that is ready to release. I want to release the compatible wear app also with only 3 features from the entire app.

I added a new module and tried compiling on the android wear device but it is taking the new module's layout instead of the original app.

How do I connect the app and wear so that it will act as a clone of the app but with only 3 features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it properly it will allow you in Developer console to upload both.
Read this for general requirements:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

This is also an example, note the application folder which is for the mobile and wearable folder which is for the Wear device. See the details in Android manifest and build gradle files, you need to follow them exactly.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace